# Cannot ssh to compute engine after suggested reboot

Tags: ssh, google-compute-engine

The last time I ssh into my compute engine instance, it suggested a system reboot. I rebooted it. After the reboot, I can no longer ssh into it. The instance is still running, the web server is still working. I can even get authentication succeeded. It than it close the connection. The log is a below.

---

```
ssh -v -i "privatekey" username@hostname

OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016

debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config

debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *

debug1: Connecting to hostname [ip] port 22.

debug1: Connection established.

debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory

debug1: identity file [key location] type -1

debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory

debug1: identity file /home/keyfile-cert type -1

debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0

debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4

debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4

debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000

debug1: Authenticating to hostname:22 as 'username'

debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent

debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received

debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org

debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256

debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none

debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none

debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY

debug1: Server host key: Server host key

debug1: Host 'hostname' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.

debug1: Found key in /home/username/.ssh/known_hosts:2

debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks

debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent

debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS

debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks

debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received

debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received

debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>

debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received

debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey

debug1: Next authentication method: publickey

debug1: Trying private key: privatekeyfile

Enter passphrase for key 'privatekeyfile':

debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).

Authenticated to hostname ([ip]:22).

debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]

debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com

debug1: Entering interactive session.

debug1: pledge: network

debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1

**Connection to hostname  closed by remote host.**

**Connection to hostname  closed.**

Transferred: sent 2256, received 1380 bytes, in 0.0 seconds

Bytes per second: sent 155684.5, received 95232.6

debug1: Exit status -1
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the debug output you have provided, I have found two resolved issues with similar output. Here are the two links found [1st link](https://serverfault.com/questions/415360/ssh-localhost-exits-with-debug1-exit-status-1) and [2nd link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/323776/why-is-my-ssh-connection-being-closed-immediately-after-pubkey-auth-succeeds). They were essentially resolved by changing the ~/.ssh permissions.